# Diretório Raiz de Aplicação Java Desktop

Tags: java

Estou com uma aplicação java desktop, sendo um jar executável e preciso sabre o diretório raiz onde o jar esta rodando. Ja pesquisei diversas forma e não encontrei o que preciso, sempre estou vendo modelos onde informo um arquivo X pra ele me retornar a localização do mesmo e o que preciso e pegar o Raiz do Jar Executável.

Agradeço.

Comment: Tente uma dessas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file

Comment: Obrigado pela indicação. Encontrei a resposta la.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar `String path = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();` para isto.

Comment: Isso não responde a pergunta. Só retorna a pasta do usuario, não a que o jar está sendo executado.

Comment: Editado, realmente a resposta anterior retorna a pasta onde o usuário executou o jar.

Answer (score 1):

Solução para o que preciso:

> The only solution that works for me on Linux, Mac and Windows:

```
public static String getJarContainingFolder(Class aclass) throws Exception {
  CodeSource codeSource = aclass.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();

  File jarFile;

  if (codeSource.getLocation() != null) {
    jarFile = new File(codeSource.getLocation().toURI());
  }
  else {
    String path = aclass.getResource(aclass.getSimpleName() + ".class").getPath();
    String jarFilePath = path.substring(path.indexOf(":") + 1, path.indexOf("!"));
    jarFilePath = URLDecoder.decode(jarFilePath, "UTF-8");
    jarFile = new File(jarFilePath);
  }
  return jarFile.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath();
}
```

encontrado no post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file